# why my android listview is not working?

Tags: android, listview

i'm new at android development and have a question about a lst view.
I'm starting a new projekt and then open the main.xml and add a lied view.

the main activity looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getBaseContext(), R.array.titles, R.layout.list_item));

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

In `R.array.titles` i have the string array and in `R.layout.list_item` I have a single textview.

now everytime i start the app in debugging mode i get the following output:

```
01-06 09:39:17.193: W/dalvikvm(367): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
01-06 09:39:17.202: E/AndroidRuntime(367): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-06 09:39:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{meine.app/meine.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 09:39:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: Adapter you are getting from createFromResource(getBaseContext(), R.array.titles, R.layout.list_item)); is expecting R.id.text1 to set resource value, and in layout R.layout.list_item it is not available, either create android.R.id.text1 in your layout, or change layout parameter to android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, please check and let me know results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call the 
*setContent(R.layout.main);*
 prior to intanciating the listView.

Comment: this is because you can not use "findViewById" before setting the layout of the activity.
As this method searches for the view you wanna instanciate in the layout of the activity, and there is no such layout provided to your activity in your case, hence fails.